# Helmet is not a valid jsx element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have this problem in the react boilerplate template.

typsecript error
'Helmet' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'Helmet' is not a valid JSX element.  TS2786

```
     7 |   return (
     8 |     <>
  >  9 |       <Helmet>
       |        ^
    10 |         <title>404 Page Not Found</title>
    11 |         <meta name="description" content="Page not found" />
    12 |       </Helmet>
```

imported as

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
```

investigating the "" shows this error

HelmetProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'HelmetProvider' is not a valid JSX element.
Type 'HelmetProvider' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.ts(2

```
`import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
```

why is this not working?

Comment: Do you have a context provider? Are you using the correct version of the library that matches the documentation you got that code from?

Comment: I just installed and ran this:
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate-cra-template

From my limited redux knowledge, i can see the, theme provider, and helmet provider wrapping the app.

Comment: That's good, please edit that information into the question itself.

Comment: VSCode was showing me the exactly same error when using the synchronous helmet package. However, a `Developer: Reload Window" was enough to "fix" it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by installing @types/react-helmet.

`npm install --save @types/react-helmet`

Comment: I am getting this error after replacing react-helmet with the async version. I placed the provider on top of the tree and I am getting the author's reported error even after install these types. Any other suggestion? Also, why types/react-helmet and not types/react-helmet-async? Thank you in advance

Comment: Apparently this is an error that happens from version 1.0.9 onwards. On their Github page there is an open issue https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async/issues/139

Comment: Same error and upgraded react-helmet-async to 1.1.2, that solved the issue

Answer (score 5):

I also hit this error using the react boilerplate template. This resolved the error for me!

```
yarn upgrade @types/react@latest
```

Comment: `npm i react@latest` and  `npm i @types/react@latest` may probably solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async#usage

I think you need to default import it, as you might be using the older version.

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet-async'
```

Comment: Changing it to default import doesnt help but it is likely an olde version taken from the boiiler plater:
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate-cra-template

Comment: @AlexanderHemming can you provide a codesandbox.

Comment: I dont think it is small enough to provide such a thing. I have however, not done anything other than start what is in the boilerplate link if you wish to try it.

Comment: @AlexanderHemming i did actually, it works for me. 

Comment: that has me confused.

Answer (score 0):

I used react 17. So I resolved it by adding this to package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
   "@types/react": "17.0.2",
   "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
},
```