# React Helmet cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-helmet

I'm trying to use `react-helmet` in a React Typescript component like so

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

interface TestComponentProps {}

const TestComponent: React.FC<TestComponentProps> = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
                <title>Content</title>
            </Helmet>
        </>
    )
}

export default TestComponent
```

But I'm getting a TS error `'Helmet' cannot be used as a JSX component`. Shown below

[image]

I've added the following dependencies with `yarn`

```
"@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
"react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
```

How can I fix this TS error?

Comment: Do any of these answers answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255300/helmet-is-not-a-valid-jsx-element. Also it seems to work fine without any fancy types packages installed: https://tsplay.dev/NdAXMm

Comment: Yeah I've gone through that but no luck. Must be some sort of versioning issue I guess, because it still doesn't work for me :/

Comment: If I remove `@types/react-helmet` I get....

`Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-helmet'. '/Users/matthewbell/Github/falconer/node_modules/react-helmet/lib/Helmet.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try npm i --save-dev @types/react-helmet if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-helmet';`

Comment: Try installing the same version of types as the lib

Comment: Tried with no luck

Comment: did you fix the error?  I've the same error.

Comment: I was never able to fix it, instead I ended up writing a custom hook to do the same thing. Here's a snippet of [the hook](https://playcode.io/992479)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem by adding to devDependencies using this command on terminal.

```
yarn add --dev @types/react-helmet
```